# How to get authenticated user in web service methods using WSS4J interceptors

Tags: java, spring, web-services, authentication, cxf

I have an Apache CXF service hosted in Spring. I am using WSS4J interceptors to validate username/password security to access the server.  Authentication works correctly, if I send wrong credentials from SoapUI I can't use the service, as expected. If I send right credentials, service works with no problems. This is my configuration in spring context file.

```
<bean id="myPasswordCallback" class="cu.datys.sias.custom.ServerPasswordCallback"/>

<jaxws:endpoint id="siasEndpoint"
                implementor="#siasImpl"
                address="/sias">
    <jaxws:features>
        <!-- Soporte WS-Addressing -->
        <!--<wsa:addressing xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing" addressingRequired="true" usingAddressingAdvisory="true" allowDuplicates="true"/>-->
    </jaxws:features>
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                    <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                    <entry key="passwordCallbackRef"
                           value-ref="myPasswordCallback" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Now I need to be able to access my authenticated user inside my service methods, something like this:

```
@WebResult(name = "UpdatePatternResponse", targetNamespace = "http://test.com/schemas/xsd/myservice/", partName = "UpdatePatternResponse")
@WebMethod(operationName = "UpdatePattern", action = "UpdatePattern")
@Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date = "2015-02-19T12:49:59.491-05:00")
public test.com.schemas.xsd.myservice.UpdatePatternResponse updatePattern(
    @WebParam(partName = "UpdatePatternRequest", name = "UpdatePatternRequest", targetNamespace = "http://test.com/schemas/xsd/myservice/")
    test.com.schemas.xsd.myservice.UpdatePatternRequest updatePatternRequest
) throws SIASFaultMessage{
    .
    .
    User myAuthenticatedUser = //HOW TO GET THE USER???
    .....
    .
    .
    .
}
```

How can I get the authenticated user inside my Apache CXF service methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this to be the only question relating to such an important subject, so I would like to share what I found for CXF 3.1.x.

The basic idea is the same as @alfredo-a illustrated. Here is the code:

```
Message message=PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
SecurityContext context=message.get(SecurityContext.class);
String userName=context.getUserPrincipal().getName();
```

I hope this is helpful to someone.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, it works. And I agree with you. This information is so import that it should be put on the official document of CXF.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  I spent a day on this stupid thing.  I agree with @JianChen... this should be in the official doc.  I say that because I studied at the official documentation the whole time and got nowhere!

Comment: I am going to mark this one as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out, thanks to this link:

[Is there a way to access the CXF message exchange from a JAX-RS REST Resource within CXF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750820/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-cxf-message-exchange-from-a-jax-rs-rest-resource-wi)

This is how to get the user name using WSSJ4 interceptors:

```
@WebResult(name = "UpdatePatternResponse", targetNamespace = "http://test.com/schemas/xsd/myservice/", partName = "UpdatePatternResponse")
@WebMethod(operationName = "UpdatePattern", action = "UpdatePattern")
@Generated(value = "org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava", date = "2015-02-19T12:49:59.491-05:00")
public test.com.schemas.xsd.myservice.UpdatePatternResponse updatePattern(
    @WebParam(partName = "UpdatePatternRequest", name = "UpdatePatternRequest", targetNamespace = "http://test.com/schemas/xsd/myservice/")
    test.com.schemas.xsd.myservice.UpdatePatternRequest updatePatternRequest
) throws SIASFaultMessage{
    .
    .
    Message message = PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
    WSUsernameTokenPrincipal principal = (WSUsernameTokenPrincipal)message.get("wss4j.principal.result");
    String userName = principal.getName();
    .
    .
    .
}
```